# C# (Xamarin) List, where and its changes

Tags: c#

I don't know where an error is. I have a list of element called `TileModel` with default values and `ObservableCollection<TileModel> list`

When I show a form in my view model I have to find in this list an element with the same name. If an element in the list exists, I copy this element in the `ObservableCollection`.

```
public ObservableCollection<TileModel> testList { get; set; }

List<TileModel> dsType = new List<TileModel>() {
    new TileModel() { Text = "Alarms", IconImage = "Alarm.png", 
                      NavigateType = typeof(Alarms) },
}
```

In a function I have this code:

```
foreach (string s in items)
{
    TileModel dm = dsType.Where(d => d.Text.RemoveTextBetween("(", ")").Trim() == s)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
    if (dm != null)
    {
        dm.Text = UpdateTextItem(dm.Text, iType);
        testList.Add(dm);
    }
}
```

`UpdateTextItem` changes the name `Text` to add the number of records. If I follow the code with F11, when I enter in the function `dsType` is the original. After `dm.Text = UpdateTextItem(dm.Text, iType);` dsType is changed this `dm.text`.

In my point of view `dm` is a new variable with in it  a value of the list but isn't an instance of an element of the list. Then why do the code change my original `dsType`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your class `TileModel` is a reference type. That means `dm` is just a reference to the original object.

By:

```
testList.Add(dm);
```

you add the reference to your testList - the object is the same if it gets changed, it also changes your object in your original list.
To Avoid this. You can add the Item like this: (If your ctor allows this)

```
var dm_new = new TileModel(dm);
dm_new .Text = UpdateTextItem(dm_new .Text, iType);
testList.Add(dm_new );
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I don't have a ctor like in your example then to resolve my issue I created a new `TileModel` and mapped each property.

Comment: Or you create an ctor for doing this, which will help you next time you face something like this ;) Reference types are often a problem to new programmers comming from c++ though you don't see it is more or less a pointer without '*'